# Adobe XD. Default state vs Hover state. Opacity is the same for both

Tags: hover, state, user-experience

1. Create rectangle.
2. Set as component.
3. Create Hover State (plus button).
4. In Default state set blue background and opacity 10%.
5. In Hover state set red background and opacity 90%.

Result
Color is saved (blue and red), opacity is the same for both: 90%.

Expected
Color is saved (blue and red), opacity is 10% (default) and 90% (hover).